# Core data query to many only shows 1 record

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, one-to-many

I have created a test project, to learn to work with Core Data. What I have done is, create two Entities:

- Client

  - name

    - relationship --> projects (To Many relationship)
- Project

  - project

    - relationship  --> clients

I have created 2 UITableViewControllers one that displays all clients and one that will show all projects related to that client.

To show all related projects I have created this method:

> ```
> -(NSArray *)relatedProjects:(Client *)client;
> {
>     NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
>
>     NSEntityDescription *e = [[model entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"Project"];
>
>     [request setEntity:e];
>
>    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", client.projects]];
>
>
>
>     NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"project"
>                                                          ascending:YES];
>     [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sd]];
>
>     NSError *error;
>     NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
>
>
>     if (!result) {
>         [NSException raise:@"Fetch failed"
>                     format:@"Reason: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
>     }
>     relatedProjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:result];
>
> //return result;
> return relatedProjects;
> ```
>
> }

Only problem is that is will only show 1 project instead of all related projects. 
If I leave out this line, then all projects are shown, but then there is no relationship between the projects and client.

> ```
>    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", client.projects]];
> ```

(for my testcase I have created 1 client with several projects, so that I know it should show more then 1 project)

So I am stuck how to solve this issue, as there are several possibilities why this isn't working:

1. Predicate is not ok
2. Relationships between client and projects are not ok
3. etc

So if there is anyone who can give me some pointers, that would be great.

Comment: have you set the inverse relationship? why don't just return `[client.projects allObjects]`?

Comment: [client.projects allObjects] give the exact same output, so only 1 record returning. How do I set the inverse relationship? I thought that was set automatically?

Comment: If you mean set the inversie relationship in the inspector, then I have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that:
you have many-to-many relationship between Client<<-->>Project (you should mark the relationship of both `projects` and `clients` as **to-many** in the editor).
You have set the inverse relationship correctly (in the model editor).
You are adding the the objects to the relationship correctly.

try changing the predicate to:
`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN clients",client.objectID]`

Comment: Thank you. It is a one to many relationship, one client can have more projects, but a project can only have one client. in Client.h file you see NSSet *projects and in project.h you see Client *clients. If I try using your predicate, the program goes into error. And Core data is to new for me, to understand why.

Comment: I have not tested this predicate. I will test it and get back to you.

Comment: I've tested this predicate, and it seem to work fine for a to-many relationship. what you described is that your relationship is not defined as many-to-many, so you are searching for projects where the client is the client you selected ==> change `clients` to `client` and the predicate to `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"client == %@,client.objectID]`

Comment: Hi, it is working now. Besides your NSPredicate I had to change some code. When saving I did this     // save changes to project and client
    [project setProject:[nameProject text]];
    [project setClients:client];
   NSSet *s = [NSSet setWithObject:project];
   [client setProjects:s]; After deleting the last to rows, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create Clint model like

Client -

```
# clientId

# clientName

# createProjects //relation to project
```

Project

```
# projectId

# project

# createdBy   // relation inverse to createProjects
```

When you are fetching the data first fetch client data and load tableView with the data. Once particular client selected fetch the projectDetails (using relation) and load tableView.

client.createdProjects will give you array of Project objects.

Comment: besides adding the ID atributes, in my eyes, it seems the same as you described. Do you know if there is a simple way to check if the entities are stored with the correct relationships? If I use NSLOG in combination with %@ it just print out something like this for the relationship "0x83b9da0 <x-coredata:///Task/tCBABB8D1-6CE6-45E2-9CDA-AE63E686BEEF6>"

Comment: those are objects of type NSEntityDescription so typecast those to Client or Project then print.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing way to much work.  If you've modelled the relationship in the model, Client already has a list of related projects.  It will be named the same as the relationship.
When you fetch the Client object, the list of projects will be a 'fault', but as soon as you access it

```
NSArray* allProjects = client.projects;
```

Core Data will realise that it isn't populated yet and go and fetch the list for you.

Quick Summary:

```
-(NSArray *)relatedProjects:(Client *)client;
{
    return client.projects;
}
```

Done.

This is in fact why you're using core data and not using sql directly ( among many other cool reasons).

Comment: NSArray * allProjects = client.projects give me this warning: "Incompatible pointer types returning 'NSSet *' from a function with result type 'NSArray *'" So does that mean that my relationship is not correct?